# How do I run apple script on a particular instance of Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, applescript

I have three instances of Firefox called -

1. Firefox
2. Firefox 2
3. Firefox 3

They all live in the Applications folder and the difference is that they have different Firefox profiles and cookies.

I'd like to run an apple script that works on a particular instance of Firefox.

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "n" using {command down}
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "l" using {command down}
        keystroke "a" using {command down}
        key code 51
        keystroke "https://google.com"
        key code 36
    end tell
end tell
```

If I run this with Firefox open then it works exactly how I want it to.

But, if Firefox is closed, but Firefox 2 or Firefox 3 are open then it has weird behavior.

It will replace the word Firefox with Firefox 2 or Firefox 3 (whichever is open and last active) and then it will run the script using that instance of Firefox which is not what I want.

Comment: There is an add on called “title” that allows you to change the name  of the Firefox window.  Maybe you can use that in conjunction with AS to identify the specific instance you want.  I run a whole  separate  instance of  FF but I append “Development” so it appears as “Firefox - Development”

Comment: As a side-note, don't put one `tell application` block inside another.  Keep them separate.  You can easily just have `tell application "Firefox" to activate` on a line of its own before your _System Events_ block.

Comment: Awesome, mind sharing why that's a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, I duplicated **Firefox** and renamed the copy as **Firefox 2**.

This was texted under **macOS High Sierra**, using different scenarios:

- Both **Firefox** and **Firefox 2** running, with **Firefox** started first.

  - **Firefox** being frontmost.
  - **Firefox 2** being frontmost.
- Both **Firefox** and **Firefox 2** running, with **Firefox 2** started first.

  - **Firefox** being frontmost.
  - **Firefox 2** being frontmost.
- Just **Firefox 2** running.

In all tested scenarios the *example* **AppleScript** *code* preformed as wanted, **Firefox** being the one acted upon, not **Firefox 2**.

I believe the key here is using the *fully qualified pathname*, e.g. `"/Applications/Firefox.app"` verses just `"Firefox"`.

```applescript
tell application "/Applications/Firefox.app" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "n" using {command down}
    delay 1
    keystroke "l" using {command down}
    keystroke "a" using {command down}
    key code 51
    keystroke "https://google.com"
    key code 36
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>